# Django modelformset_factory() adding field manually in views

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Disclaimer: I am new at Django so I'm sure my code is ugly.

**Problem**: 
My current Model is built as follows:

```
class person(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    date = models.DateField()
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    belongs_to_group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='group', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    belongs_to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

I have built a modelformset_factory for this using the following code:

```
personModelFormset = modelformset_factory(
    person,
    fields=('email', 'date' , 'phone_number', 'name'),
    extra=1)
```

This makes the fields the form renders in the HTML email, date , phone_number, and name. This means that to successfully save the form to the database, I need to also add the fields `belongs_to_group` and `belongs_to_user` manually since the website user shouldn't be able to edit these (they should be automatically generated).

**Attempted Solution**:
To try to do this, I used the following view:

```
def classes(request):


    #add form creation method here
    user = request.user  
    group = value #taken from another form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_2 = personModelFormset (request.POST)

        if form_2.is_valid():            
            for form in form_2:
                    form.belongs_to_group = value
                    form.belongs_to_user = user
                    form.save()


            return redirect('home')
```

But this does not append the information to the form. This method works for me in a normal `modelform`, so I think I'm not using the `modelformset_factory` correctly. Does anyone know how I should correctly append the "behind the scenes" model fields to the formsetfactory? Thank you!

Comment: No, that method does *not* work in a model form. You missed the `obj = form.save(commit=False)` and then assign the `belongs_to_x` to `obj` rather than `form`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. If you want to form that as an answer I can accept it